# All resources exist yet HTTP 404 error occurs frequently?

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

A HTTP 404 error is happening frequently (although not all the time) for a particular web application.  The file in question "search.aspx" exists (and always has).

Is there some setting in IIS that could cause the HTTP 404 error to occur even though all files exist on the webserver?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out the website has more than one node.  The search.aspx file was on one node, but not the other.